# XLS report do not generating in Rails test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, rspec, spreadsheet

I am using for generating document.xls report this

gem 'excel_rails'
  gem 'spreadsheet'

When i trying to get it from my browser it looks everything works great, but when i am trying to access this from my spec like this

```
get :document, { format: 'xls' }
```

it is going to be like this

```
1) ***Controller GET document.xls assigns project_test_exceptions
 Failure/Error: get :document, document_params
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   ***/document.xls.rxls:1: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting keyword_end
   ...t_buffer;;sio = StringIO.new; .write(sio); sio.string
   ...                               ^
 # ./app/***_controller.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in document'
 # ./app/***_controller.rb:55:in `document'
 # ./spec/***_spec.rb:301:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

where are can be errors?

Comment: Solution did not found, so  i am using  "to_spreadsheet" gem(https://github.com/glebm/to_spreadsheet) for xls generation

Answer (score 0):

You should take a closer look at [this](https://github.com/asanghi/excel_rails/blob/master/lib/excel_rails.rb#L30) line in `excel_rails` gem. It looks for a template to generate an xls file, so you just need to add a [render_views](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/controller-specs/render-views) method to your spec file and tests should pass.